# Angularjs Controller Directive

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

How can i call a function from Directive?
when the GetAllActivityActionDetails method gets called, function is not firing.
 contrller function :

```
 function GetAllActivityActionDetails() {
        alert("GetAllActivityActionDetails");
}
```

Directive is :

```
app.directive("bwUpload", ['$log', '$http',  function ($log, $http) {
    return {

        scope: { project: "=", activity: "=", action: "=", document: "=" },

        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    $log.log('onload.byteLength: ' + loadEvent.target.result.byteLength);                    
                    scope.$apply(function () {                        
                        var p = 'project_id=' + scope.project._id + '&activity_id=' + scope.activity._id +
                              '&action_name=' + scope.action.name + '&document_id=' + scope.document._id

                        var config = {

                            url: 'baf/DocumentUpload?' + p,
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' },
                            data: new Uint8Array(loadEvent.target.result),
                            transformRequest: []
                        };

                        $http(config).then(
                          function (resp) {
                              var response = resp.data;
                              $log.log("DocumentUpload response (fileName, length): " + response.fileName + ", " + response.length);
                              alert('Document Uploded.');
                              //bwGlobals.refreshView()
                              alert(scope.activity._id);

                              //GetAllActivityActionDetails(scope.activity._id);
                              scope.$apply("GetAllActivityActionDetails()");
                              alert("GetAllActivityActionDetails");
                          },
                          function (errResponse) { alert(errResponse); }
                        );
                    });

                }
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

i want to call GetAllActivityActionDetails()form directive but it is not working

Comment: you can see i also done with :
GetAllActivityActionDetails(scope.activity._id);
but same result // not firing

Comment: why are you using directive to do a post method? just curious as I would do this as a service.

Comment: add `GetAllActivityActionDetails` in you directive scope property like 
`scope:{GetAllActivityActionDetails : '&' }` and then just call `$scope.GetAllActivityActionDetails`

Comment: $scope.GetAllActivityActionDetails() is not firing for me @Nilesh

Comment: Did u assign that function in your html?

Comment: yes
 function GetAllActivityActionDetails(sActivityID) {
//code here
}

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a good practice of angular pattern, you can create the function in global and call from the directive using window.

```js
var GetAllActivityActionDetails = function () {
  alert("GetAllActivityActionDetails");
}
```

And then in the directive trigger it like:

```
window.GetAllActivityActionDetails();
```